# I want to sort two lists in decreasing order on basis of percentage marks scored on each subject

Tags: c#, list, sorting

I have two lists, one contains marks scored on each subject and the second one holds total marks corresponding each subject. now I want to sort both lists in decreasing order on basis of percentage marks scored on each subject.

Comment: Please [edit] with a couple of examples and code for your lists. And specific questions that you are having trouble with.

Answer (score 0):

Taking your post literally, if you have a class Grade that has a property Score, and the grades are in a List:

```
List<Grade> sortedEnglishGradesList = englishGradesList.OrderByDesc(g=>g.Score);
```

You'll need to include `using System.Linq` at the top of the file if it's not there already